# Picking a Random Word from a list in python?

Tags: python, random, word-list

In Python 3, how would I print a random word from a list of words?

Comment: **See instead:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834636/random-word-generator-python

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) function:

```
>>> import random
>>> a = ["Stack", "Overflow", "rocks"]
>>> print(random.choice(a))
rocks
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, I knew it was simple, but I forgot how to do it.

Comment: Noah, accept his answer if it answered your question best.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice("hello world".split())
'hello'
>>> random.choice("hello world".split())
'world'
```

Comment: Did you actually run it until you got this output? Or did you fake it =P

Comment: @Falmarri: About a 50/50 chance, wouldn't you say?

Comment: You have a 25% chance of getting this output.

Comment: Are we supposed to test the code we post on here? :)

Comment: The fact that the first word was "hello" doesn't affect the 50/50 chances of second one being "world" does it?

Comment: No, @martineau, it doesn't.  It was a 50% chance of the first one being 'hello', and a 50% chance of the second being 'world'.  .5 * .5 = .25.

Comment: OK, I get it...but I'm not sure what the big deal is about the output happening to be "hello" followed by "world" since the probability of that is exactly the same as it being any other combination (even if it's less than 50/50).

Answer (score 3):

```
str='book pen paper pencil'
x=str.split()
print(x)
import random
print(random.choice(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str='book pen paper pencil'
x=str.split()
print(x)
y=len(x)
import random
z=random.randrange(-1,y)
print(x[z])
```

Comment: Simply: `random.choice(x)`

Comment: its a logic without using any random sequences. any way@AChampion thank you for editing my code.