# Random word generator- Python

Tags: python, random, python-3.3, word-list

So i'm basically working on a project where the computer takes a word from a list of words and jumbles it up for the user. there's only one problem: I don't want to keep having to write tons of words in the list, so i'm wondering if there's a way to import a ton of random words so even I don't know what it is, and then I could enjoy the game too? This is the coding of the whole program, it only has 6 words that i put in:

```
import random

WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer",  "xylophone")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = word
jumble = ""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
print(
"""
      Welcome to WORD JUMBLE!!!

      Unscramble the leters to make a word.
      (press the enter key at prompt to quit)
      """
      )
print("The jumble is:", jumble)
guess = input("Your guess: ")
while guess != correct and guess != "":
    print("Sorry, that's not it")
    guess = input("Your guess: ")
if guess == correct:
    print("That's it, you guessed it!\n")
print("Thanks for playing")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Use a text file of words? `/usr/share/dict/words` is common *nix platforms, or there's other wordlists you can use...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free word list for use programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772922/free-word-list-for-use-programatically)

Comment: **See also:** novelty python demo that does not require loading any external word list [https://github.com/dreftymac/trypublic/blob/master/lab2021/python-wordlist/random_word_demo_py37.py](https://github.com/dreftymac/trypublic/blob/master/lab2021/python-wordlist/random_word_demo_py37.py) dmid://uu669smist1628779

Answer (score 114, accepted):

## Reading a local word list

If you're doing this repeatedly, I would download it locally and pull from the local file. *nix users can use `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Example:

```
word_file = "/usr/share/dict/words"
WORDS = open(word_file).read().splitlines()
```

## Pulling from a remote dictionary

If you want to pull from a remote dictionary, here are a couple of ways. The requests library makes this really easy (you'll have to `pip install requests`):

```
import requests

word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"

response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
```

Alternatively, you can use the built in urllib2.

```
import urllib2

word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"

response = urllib2.urlopen(word_site)
txt = response.read()
WORDS = txt.splitlines()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this really helped, i put your answer as the accepted answer and i voted up :)

Comment: Note that the link `http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/share/dict/web2?rev=1.12;content-type=text%2Fplain` is now dead...

Comment: @Eric - :( Guess I'll just have to host a word list.

Comment: @Eric, this works great; word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain".
It's hosted with ViewVc formatting, and they mentioned the download link is the best way to go; http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.cvs.viewcvs.user/5453 .
Can you believe this 25k dictionary is 21 years old!!?? I love the web. //oops truncates. will edit post.

Comment: the used link seems deprecated, use https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000

Comment: users beware... that MIT wordlist contains some VERY inappropriate words.

Answer (score 19):

## Solution for Python 3

For Python3 the following code grabs the word list from the web and returns a list. Answer based on [accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18835426/4038393) by Kyle Kelley.

```
import urllib.request

word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(word_url)
long_txt = response.read().decode()
words = long_txt.splitlines()
```

Output:

```
>>> words
['a', 'AAA', 'AAAS', 'aardvark', 'Aarhus', 'Aaron', 'ABA', 'Ababa',
 'aback', 'abacus', 'abalone', 'abandon', 'abase', 'abash', 'abate',
 'abbas', 'abbe', 'abbey', 'abbot', 'Abbott', 'abbreviate', ... ]
```

And to generate (because it was my objective) a list of 1) upper case only words, 2) only "name like" words, and 3) a sort-of-realistic-but-fun sounding random name:

```
import random
upper_words = [word for word in words if word[0].isupper()]
name_words  = [word for word in upper_words if not word.isupper()]
rand_name   = ' '.join([name_words[random.randint(0, len(name_words))] for i in range(2)])
```

And some random names:

```
>>> for n in range(10):
        ' '.join([name_words[random.randint(0,len(name_words))] for i in range(2)])

    'Semiramis Sicilian'
    'Julius Genevieve'
    'Rwanda Cohn'
    'Quito Sutherland'
    'Eocene Wheller'
    'Olav Jove'
    'Weldon Pappas'
    'Vienna Leyden'
    'Io Dave'
    'Schwartz Stromberg'
```

Comment: I got `404` using this code till I set `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}` then modified the code `req = urllib.request.Request(word_url, headers=headers)` and `response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)`.

Comment: It's way better to just download that words file, about 200Kb than re-downloading and rely on the connection.

Answer (score 5):

There is a package [random_word](https://pypi.org/project/Random-Word/) could implement this request very conveniently:

```
 $ pip install random-word

from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords()

# Return a single random word
r.get_random_word()
# Return list of Random words
r.get_random_words()
# Return Word of the day
r.word_of_the_day()
```

Comment: NOTE:   This calls the API at Wordnik.com to get random words.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of dictionary files available online - if you're on linux, a lot of (all?) distros come with an /etc/dictionaries-common/words file, which you can easily parse (`words = open('/etc/dictionaries-common/words').readlines()`, eg) for use.

Comment: can you edit my code, to see how it would look like if i wanted all the words from this website? http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/share/dict/web2?rev=1.12;content-type=text%2Fplain

Answer (score 1):

## get the words online

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url="https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?revision=61569&view=co"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
print(webpage)
```

Randomizing the first 500 words

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import random


url="https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?revision=61569&view=co"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
first500 = webpage[:500].split("\n")
random.shuffle(first500)
print(first500)
```

Output

['abnegation', 'able', 'aborning', 'Abigail', 'Abidjan', 'ablaze', 'abolish', 'abbe', 'above', 'abort', 'aberrant', 'aboriginal', 'aborigine', 'Aberdeen', 'Abbott', 'Abernathy', 'aback', 'abate', 'abominate', 'AAA', 'abc', 'abed', 'abhorred', 'abolition', 'ablate', 'abbey', 'abbot', 'Abelson', 'ABA', 'Abner', 'abduct', 'aboard', 'Abo', 'abalone', 'a', 'abhorrent', 'Abelian', 'aardvark', 'Aarhus', 'Abe', 'abjure', 'abeyance', 'Abel', 'abetting', 'abash', 'AAAS', 'abdicate', 'abbreviate', 'abnormal', 'abject', 'abacus', 'abide', 'abominable', 'abode', 'abandon', 'abase', 'Ababa', 'abdominal', 'abet', 'abbas', 'aberrate', 'abdomen', 'abetted', 'abound', 'Aaron', 'abhor', 'ablution', 'abeyant', 'about']

Comment: what import is necessary for `requests`?

Comment: import requests

Comment: @spinup you want to import requests because it is not a global. As a result, you need to import the requests module

Comment: request is the module that contains code that let's you grab text from a web page among other stuffs

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_letters
x = "".join(random.sample(letters,5))
print(x)
```

Above, `letters` will contain all ASCII letter characters (lowercase & uppercase) like so:

```py
>>> print(letters)
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Using `random.sample` will provide you with a list of the total number of items (characters in this case) from the given object (a `string` object here) based on the number you want (`random.sample(<string>, <# of random parts>`).

```py
>>> random.sample(letters, 5)
>>> ['j', 'e', 'u', 'g', 'k']
```

Finally,

`x = "".join(...)` will join together the returned list with *no spaces* because of `"".` which can be changed to `" ".` if you want spaces in between each letter.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: Does this really do what OP wants? They seem to be looking for a list of real words, not completely random strings like `xqqpl` or `ajhye`. Please read [answer]. Note also that this question is **8.5 years old** and already has 5 answers. With questions like this it is even _more_ important to explain your solution. Help us understand why this is better than what's already posted.

Answer (score 0):

here's 2286 words from [here.](https://github.com/bevacqua/correcthorse/blob/master/wordlist.json)

```py
words = ["a", "ability", "able", "about", "above", "abroad", "absence", "absent", "absolute", "accept", "accident", "accord", "account", "accuse", "accustom", "ache", "across", "act", "action", "active", "actor", "actress", "actual", "add", "address", "admire", "admission", "admit", "adopt", "adoption", "advance", "advantage", "adventure", "advertise", "advice", "advise", "affair", "afford", "afraid", "after", "afternoon", "again", "against", "age", "agency", "agent", "ago", "agree", "agriculture", "ahead", "aim", "air", "airplane", "alike", "alive", "all", "allow", "allowance", "almost", "alone", "along", "aloud", "already", "also", "although", "altogether", "always", "ambition", "ambitious", "among", "amongst", "amount", "amuse", "ancient", "and", "anger", "angle", "angry", "animal", "annoy", "annoyance", "another", "answer", "anxiety", "anxious", "any", "anybody", "anyhow", "anyone", "anything", "anyway", "anywhere", "apart", "apology", "appear", "appearance", "applaud", "applause", "apple", "application", "apply", "appoint", "approve", "arch", "argue", "arise", "arm", "army", "around", "arrange", "arrest", "arrive", "arrow", "art", "article", "artificial", "as", "ash", "ashamed", "aside", "ask", "asleep", "association", "astonish", "at", "attack", "attempt", "attend", "attention", "attentive", "attract", "attraction", "attractive", "audience", "aunt", "autumn", "avenue", "average", "avoid", "avoidance", "awake", "away", "awkward", "axe", "baby", "back", "backward", "bad", "bag", "baggage", "bake", "balance", "ball", "band", "bank", "bar", "barber", "bare", "bargain", "barrel", "base", "basic", "basin", "basis", "basket", "bath", "bathe", "battery", "battle", "bay", "be", "beak", "beam", "bean", "bear", "beard", "beast", "beat", "beauty", "because", "become", "bed", "bedroom", "before", "beg", "begin", "behave", "behavior", "behind", "being", "belief", "believe", "bell", "belong", "below", "belt", "bend", "beneath", "berry", "beside", "besides", "best", "better", "between", "beyond", "bicycle", "big", "bill", "bind", "bird", "birth", "bit", "bite", "bitter", "black", "blade", "blame", "bleed", "bless", "blind", "block", "blood", "blow", "blue", "board", "boast", "boat", "body", "boil", "bold", "bone", "book", "border", "borrow", "both", "bottle", "bottom", "bound", "boundary", "bow", "bowl", "box", "boy", "brain", "branch", "brass", "brave", "bravery", "bread", "breadth", "break", "breakfast", "breath", "breathe", "bribe", "bribery", "brick", "bridge", "bright", "brighten", "bring", "broad", "broadcast", "brother", "brown", "brush", "bucket", "build", "bunch", "bundle", "burn", "burst", "bury", "bus", "bush", "business", "businesslike", "businessman", "busy", "but", "butter", "button", "buy", "by", "cage", "cake", "calculate", "calculation", "calculator", "call", "calm", "camera", "camp", "can", "canal", "cap", "cape", "capital", "captain", "car", "card", "care", "carriage", "carry", "cart", "case", "castle", "cat", "catch", "cattle", "cause", "caution", "cautious", "cave", "cent", "center", "century", "ceremony", "certain", "certainty", "chain", "chair", "chairman", "chalk", "chance", "change", "character", "charge", "charm", "cheap", "cheat", "check", "cheer", "cheese", "chest", "chicken", "chief", "child", "childhood", "chimney", "choice", "choose", "christmas", "church", "circle", "circular", "citizen", "city", "civilize", "claim", "class", "classification", "classify", "clay", "clean", "clear", "clerk", "clever", "cliff", "climb", "clock", "close", "cloth", "clothe", "cloud", "club", "coal", "coarse", "coast", "coat", "coffee", "coin", "cold", "collar", "collect", "collection", "collector", "college", "colony", "color", "comb", "combine", "come", "comfort", "command", "commerce", "commercial", "committee", "common", "companion", "companionship", "company", "compare", "comparison", "compete", "competition", "competitor", "complain", "complaint", "complete", "completion", "complicate", "complication", "compose", "composition", "concern", "condition", "confess", "confession", "confidence", "confident", "confidential", "confuse", "confusion", "congratulate", "congratulation", "connect", "connection", "conquer", "conqueror", "conquest", "conscience", "conscious", "consider", "contain", "content", "continue", "control", "convenience", "convenient", "conversation", "cook", "cool", "copper", "copy", "cork", "corn", "corner", "correct", "correction", "cost", "cottage", "cotton", "cough", "could", "council", "count", "country", "courage", "course", "court", "cousin", "cover", "cow", "coward", "cowardice", "crack", "crash", "cream", "creature", "creep", "crime", "criminal", "critic", "crop", "cross", "crowd", "crown", "cruel", "crush", "cry", "cultivate", "cultivation", "cultivator", "cup", "cupboard", "cure", "curious", "curl", "current", "curse", "curtain", "curve", "cushion", "custom", "customary", "customer", "cut", "daily", "damage", "damp", "dance", "danger", "dare", "dark", "darken", "date", "daughter", "day", "daylight", "dead", "deaf", "deafen", "deal", "dear", "death", "debt", "decay", "deceit", "deceive", "decide", "decision", "decisive", "declare", "decrease", "deed", "deep", "deepen", "deer", "defeat", "defend", "defendant", "defense", "degree", "delay", "delicate", "delight", "deliver", "delivery", "demand", "department", "depend", "dependence", "dependent", "depth", "descend", "descendant", "descent", "describe", "description", "desert", "deserve", "desire", "desk", "despair", "destroy", "destruction", "destructive", "detail", "determine", "develop", "devil", "diamond", "dictionary", "die", "difference", "different", "difficult", "difficulty", "dig", "dine", "dinner", "dip", "direct", "direction", "director", "dirt", "disagree", "disappear", "disappearance", "disappoint", "disapprove", "discipline", "discomfort", "discontent", "discover", "discovery", "discuss", "discussion", "disease", "disgust", "dish", "dismiss", "disregard", "disrespect", "dissatisfaction", "dissatisfy", "distance", "distant", "distinguish", "district", "disturb", "ditch", "dive", "divide", "division", "do", "doctor", "dog", "dollar", "donkey", "door", "dot", "double", "doubt", "down", "dozen", "drag", "draw", "drawer", "dream", "dress", "drink", "drive", "drop", "drown", "drum", "dry", "duck", "due", "dull", "during", "dust", "duty", "each", "eager", "ear", "early", "earn", "earnest", "earth", "ease", "east", "eastern", "easy", "eat", "edge", "educate", "education", "educator", "effect", "effective", "efficiency", "efficient", "effort", "egg", "either", "elastic", "elder", "elect", "election", "electric", "electrician", "elephant", "else", "elsewhere", "empire", "employ", "employee", "empty", "enclose", "enclosure", "encourage", "end", "enemy", "engine", "engineer", "english", "enjoy", "enough", "enter", "entertain", "entire", "entrance", "envelope", "envy", "equal", "escape", "especially", "essence", "essential", "even", "evening", "event", "ever", "everlasting", "every", "everybody", "everyday", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "evil", "exact", "examine", "example", "excellence", "excellent", "except", "exception", "excess", "excessive", "exchange", "excite", "excuse", "exercise", "exist", "existence", "expect", "expense", "expensive", "experience", "experiment", "explain", "explode", "explore", "explosion", "explosive", "express", "expression", "extend", "extension", "extensive", "extent", "extra", "extraordinary", "extreme", "eye", "face", "fact", "factory", "fade", "fail", "failure", "faint", "fair", "faith", "fall", "FALSE", "fame", "familiar", "family", "fan", "fancy", "far", "farm", "fashion", "fast", "fasten", "fat", "fate", "father", "fatten", "fault", "favor", "favorite", "fear", "feast", "feather", "feed", "feel", "fellow", "fellowship", "female", "fence", "fever", "few", "field", "fierce", "fight", "figure", "fill", "film", "find", "fine", "finger", "finish", "fire", "firm", "first", "fish", "fit", "fix", "flag", "flame", "flash", "flat", "flatten", "flavor", "flesh", "float", "flood", "floor", "flour", "flow", "flower", "fly", "fold", "follow", "fond", "food", "fool", "foot", "for", "forbid", "force", "foreign", "forest", "forget", "forgive", "fork", "form", "formal", "former", "forth", "fortunate", "fortune", "forward", "frame", "framework", "free", "freedom", "freeze", "frequency", "frequent", "fresh", "friend", "friendly", "friendship", "fright", "frighten", "from", "front", "fruit", "fry", "full", "fun", "funeral", "funny", "fur", "furnish", "furniture", "further", "future", "gaiety", "gain", "gallon", "game", "gap", "garage", "garden", "gas", "gate", "gather", "gay", "general", "generous", "gentle", "gentleman", "get", "gift", "girl", "give", "glad", "glass", "glory", "go", "goat", "god", "gold", "golden", "good", "govern", "governor", "grace", "gradual", "grain", "grammar", "grammatical", "grand", "grass", "grateful", "grave", "gray", "grease", "great", "greed", "green", "greet", "grind", "ground", "group", "grow", "growth", "guard", "guess", "guest", "guide", "guilt", "gun", "habit", "hair", "half", "hall", "hammer", "hand", "handkerchief", "handle", "handshake", "handwriting", "hang", "happen", "happy", "harbor", "hard", "harden", "hardly", "harm", "harvest", "haste", "hasten", "hat", "hate", "hatred", "have", "hay", "he", "head", "headache", "headdress", "heal", "health", "heap", "hear", "heart", "heat", "heaven", "heavenly", "heavy", "height", "heighten", "hello", "help", "here", "hesitate", "hesitation", "hide", "high", "highway", "hill", "hinder", "hindrance", "hire", "history", "hit", "hold", "hole", "holiday", "hollow", "holy", "home", "homecoming", "homemade", "homework", "honest", "honesty", "honor", "hook", "hope", "horizon", "horizontal", "horse", "hospital", "host", "hot", "hotel", "hour", "house", "how", "however", "human", "humble", "hunger", "hunt", "hurrah", "hurry", "hurt", "husband", "hut", "I", "ice", "idea", "ideal", "idle", "if", "ill", "imaginary", "imaginative", "imagine", "imitate", "imitation", "immediate", "immense", "importance", "important", "impossible", "improve", "in", "inch", "include", "inclusive", "increase", "indeed", "indoor", "industry", "influence", "influential", "inform", "ink", "inn", "inquire", "inquiry", "insect", "inside", "instant", "instead", "instrument", "insult", "insurance", "insure", "intend", "intention", "interest", "interfere", "interference", "international", "interrupt", "interruption", "into", "introduce", "introduction", "invent", "invention", "inventor", "invite", "inward", "iron", "island", "it", "jaw", "jealous", "jealousy", "jewel", "join", "joint", "joke", "journey", "joy", "judge", "juice", "jump", "just", "justice", "keep", "key", "kick", "kill", "kind", "king", "kingdom", "kiss", "kitchen", "knee", "kneel", "knife", "knock", "knot", "know", "knowledge", "lack", "ladder", "lady", "lake", "lamp", "land", "landlord", "language", "large", "last", "late", "lately", "latter", "laugh", "laughter", "law", "lawyer", "lay", "lazy", "lead", "leadership", "leaf", "lean", "learn", "least", "leather", "leave", "left", "leg", "lend", "length", "lengthen", "less", "lessen", "lesson", "let", "letter", "level", "liar", "liberty", "librarian", "library", "lid", "lie", "life", "lift", "light", "lighten", "like", "likely", "limb", "limit", "line", "lip", "lipstick", "liquid", "list", "listen", "literary", "literature", "little", "live", "load", "loaf", "loan", "local", "lock", "lodge", "log", "lonely", "long", "look", "loose", "loosen", "lord", "lose", "loss", "lot", "loud", "love", "lovely", "low", "loyal", "loyalty", "luck", "lump", "lunch", "lung", "machine", "machinery", "mad", "madden", "mail", "main", "make", "male", "man", "manage", "mankind", "manner", "manufacture", "many", "map", "march", "mark", "market", "marriage", "marry", "mass", "master", "mat", "match", "material", "matter", "may", "maybe", "meal", "mean", "meantime", "meanwhile", "measure", "meat", "mechanic", "mechanism", "medical", "medicine", "meet", "melt", "member", "membership", "memory", "mend", "mention", "merchant", "mercy", "mere", "merry", "message", "messenger", "metal", "middle", "might", "mild", "mile", "milk", "mill", "mind", "mine", "mineral", "minister", "minute", "miserable", "misery", "miss", "mistake", "mix", "mixture", "model", "moderate", "moderation", "modern", "modest", "modesty", "moment", "momentary", "money", "monkey", "month", "moon", "moonlight", "moral", "more", "moreover", "morning", "most", "mother", "motherhood", "motherly", "motion", "motor", "mountain", "mouse", "mouth", "move", "much", "mud", "multiplication", "multiply", "murder", "music", "musician", "must", "mystery", "nail", "name", "narrow", "nation", "native", "nature", "near", "neat", "necessary", "necessity", "neck", "need", "needle", "neglect", "neighbor", "neighborhood", "neither", "nephew", "nest", "net", "network", "never", "new", "news", "newspaper", "next", "nice", "niece", "night", "no", "noble", "nobody", "noise", "none", "noon", "nor", "north", "northern", "nose", "not", "note", "notebook", "nothing", "notice", "noun", "now", "nowadays", "nowhere", "nuisance", "number", "numerous", "nurse", "nursery", "nut", "oar", "obedience", "obedient", "obey", "object", "objection", "observe", "occasion", "ocean", "of", "off", "offend", "offense", "offer", "office", "officer", "official", "often", "oil", "old", "old-fashioned", "omission", "omit", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", "open", "operate", "operation", "operator", "opinion", "opportunity", "oppose", "opposite", "opposition", "or", "orange", "order", "ordinary", "organ", "organize", "origin", "ornament", "other", "otherwise", "ought", "ounce", "out", "outline", "outside", "outward", "over", "overcome", "overflow", "owe", "own", "ownership", "pack", "package", "pad", "page", "pain", "paint", "pair", "pale", "pan", "paper", "parcel", "pardon", "parent", "park", "part", "particle", "particular", "partner", "party", "pass", "passage", "passenger", "past", "paste", "pastry", "path", "patience", "patient", "patriotic", "pattern", "pause", "paw", "pay", "peace", "pearl", "peculiar", "pen", "pencil", "penny", "people", "per", "perfect", "perfection", "perform", "performance", "perhaps", "permanent", "permission", "permit", "person", "persuade", "persuasion", "pet", "photograph", "photography", "pick", "picture", "piece", "pig", "pigeon", "pile", "pin", "pinch", "pink", "pint", "pipe", "pity", "place", "plain", "plan", "plant", "plaster", "plate", "play", "pleasant", "please", "pleasure", "plenty", "plow", "plural", "pocket", "poem", "poet", "point", "poison", "police", "polish", "polite", "political", "politician", "politics", "pool", "poor", "popular", "population", "position", "possess", "possession", "possessor", "possible", "post", "postpone", "pot", "pound", "pour", "poverty", "powder", "power", "practical", "practice", "praise", "pray", "preach", "precious", "prefer", "preference", "prejudice", "prepare", "presence", "present", "preserve", "president", "press", "pressure", "pretend", "pretense", "pretty", "prevent", "prevention", "price", "pride", "priest", "print", "prison", "private", "prize", "probable", "problem", "procession", "produce", "product", "production", "profession", "profit", "program", "progress", "promise", "prompt", "pronounce", "pronunciation", "proof", "proper", "property", "proposal", "propose", "protect", "protection", "proud", "prove", "provide", "public", "pull", "pump", "punctual", "punish", "pupil", "pure", "purple", "purpose", "push", "put", "puzzle", "qualification", "qualify", "quality", "quantity", "quarrel", "quart", "quarter", "queen", "question", "quick", "quiet", "quite", "rabbit", "race", "radio", "rail", "railroad", "rain", "raise", "rake", "rank", "rapid", "rare", "rate", "rather", "raw", "ray", "razor", "reach", "read", "ready", "real", "realize", "reason", "reasonable", "receipt", "receive", "recent", "recognition", "recognize", "recommend", "record", "red", "redden", "reduce", "reduction", "refer", "reference", "reflect", "reflection", "refresh", "refuse", "regard", "regret", "regular", "rejoice", "relate", "relation", "relative", "relief", "relieve", "religion", "remain", "remark", "remedy", "remember", "remind", "rent", "repair", "repeat", "repetition", "replace", "reply", "report", "represent", "representative", "reproduce", "reproduction", "republic", "reputation", "request", "rescue", "reserve", "resign", "resist", "resistance", "respect", "responsible", "rest", "restaurant", "result", "retire", "return", "revenge", "review", "reward", "ribbon", "rice", "rich", "rid", "ride", "right", "ring", "ripe", "ripen", "rise", "risk", "rival", "rivalry", "river", "road", "roar", "roast", "rob", "robbery", "rock", "rod", "roll", "roof", "room", "root", "rope", "rot", "rotten", "rough", "round", "row", "royal", "royalty", "rub", "rubber", "rubbish", "rude", "rug", "ruin", "rule", "run", "rush", "rust", "sacred", "sacrifice", "sad", "sadden", "saddle", "safe", "safety", "sail", "sailor", "sake", "salary", "sale", "salesman", "salt", "same", "sample", "sand", "satisfaction", "satisfactory", "satisfy", "sauce", "saucer", "save", "saw", "say", "scale", "scarce", "scatter", "scene", "scenery", "scent", "school", "science", "scientific", "scientist", "scissors", "scold", "scorn", "scrape", "scratch", "screen", "screw", "sea", "search", "season", "seat", "second", "secrecy", "secret", "secretary", "see", "seed", "seem", "seize", "seldom", "self", "selfish", "sell", "send", "sense", "sensitive", "sentence", "separate", "separation", "serious", "servant", "serve", "service", "set", "settle", "several", "severe", "sew", "shade", "shadow", "shake", "shall", "shallow", "shame", "shape", "share", "sharp", "sharpen", "shave", "she", "sheep", "sheet", "shelf", "shell", "shelter", "shield", "shilling", "shine", "ship", "shirt", "shock", "shoe", "shoot", "shop", "shore", "short", "shorten", "should", "shoulder", "shout", "show", "shower", "shut", "sick", "side", "sight", "sign", "signal", "signature", "silence", "silent", "silk", "silver", "simple", "simplicity", "since", "sincere", "sing", "single", "sink", "sir", "sister", "sit", "situation", "size", "skill", "skin", "skirt", "sky", "slave", "slavery", "sleep", "slide", "slight", "slip", "slippery", "slope", "slow", "small", "smell", "smile", "smoke", "smooth", "snake", "snow", "so", "soap", "social", "society", "sock", "soft", "soften", "soil", "soldier", "solemn", "solid", "solution", "solve", "some", "somebody", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "son", "song", "soon", "sore", "sorrow", "sorry", "sort", "soul", "sound", "soup", "sour", "south", "sow", "space", "spade", "spare", "speak", "special", "speech", "speed", "spell", "spend", "spill", "spin", "spirit", "spit", "spite", "splendid", "split", "spoil", "spoon", "sport", "spot", "spread", "spring", "square", "staff", "stage", "stain", "stair", "stamp", "stand", "standard", "staple", "star", "start", "state", "station", "stay", "steady", "steam", "steel", "steep", "steer", "stem", "step", "stick", "stiff", "stiffen", "still", "sting", "stir", "stock", "stocking", "stomach", "stone", "stop", "store", "storm", "story", "stove", "straight", "straighten", "strange", "strap", "straw", "stream", "street", "strength", "strengthen", "stretch", "strict", "strike", "string", "strip", "stripe", "stroke", "strong", "struggle", "student", "study", "stuff", "stupid", "subject", "substance", "succeed", "success", "such", "suck", "sudden", "suffer", "sugar", "suggest", "suggestion", "suit", "summer", "sun", "supper", "supply", "support", "suppose", "sure", "surface", "surprise", "surround", "suspect", "suspicion", "suspicious", "swallow", "swear", "sweat", "sweep", "sweet", "sweeten", "swell", "swim", "swing", "sword", "sympathetic", "sympathy", "system", "table", "tail", "tailor", "take", "talk", "tall", "tame", "tap", "taste", "tax", "taxi", "tea", "teach", "tear", "telegraph", "telephone", "tell", "temper", "temperature", "temple", "tempt", "tend", "tender", "tent", "term", "terrible", "test", "than", "thank", "that", "the", "theater", "theatrical", "then", "there", "therefore", "these", "they", "thick", "thicken", "thief", "thin", "thing", "think", "thirst", "this", "thorn", "thorough", "those", "though", "thread", "threat", "threaten", "throat", "through", "throw", "thumb", "thunder", "thus", "ticket", "tide", "tidy", "tie", "tight", "tighten", "till", "time", "tin", "tip", "tire", "title", "to", "tobacco", "today", "toe", "together", "tomorrow", "ton", "tongue", "tonight", "too", "tool", "tooth", "top", "total", "touch", "tough", "tour", "toward", "towel", "tower", "town", "toy", "track", "trade", "train", "translate", "translation", "translator", "trap", "travel", "tray", "treasure", "treasury", "treat", "tree", "tremble", "trial", "tribe", "trick", "trip", "trouble", "true", "trunk", "trust", "truth", "try", "tube", "tune", "turn", "twist", "type", "ugly", "umbrella", "uncle", "under", "underneath", "understand", "union", "unit", "unite", "unity", "universal", "universe", "university", "unless", "until", "up", "upon", "upper", "uppermost", "upright", "upset", "urge", "urgent", "use", "usual", "vain", "valley", "valuable", "value", "variety", "various", "veil", "verb", "verse", "very", "vessel", "victory", "view", "village", "violence", "violent", "virtue", "visit", "visitor", "voice", "vote", "vowel", "voyage", "wage", "waist", "wait", "waiter", "wake", "walk", "wall", "wander", "want", "war", "warm", "warmth", "warn", "wash", "waste", "watch", "water", "wave", "wax", "way", "we", "weak", "weaken", "wealth", "weapon", "wear", "weather", "weave", "weed", "week", "weekday", "weekend", "weigh", "weight", "welcome", "well", "west", "western", "wet", "what", "whatever", "wheat", "wheel", "when", "whenever", "where", "wherever", "whether", "which", "whichever", "while", "whip", "whisper", "whistle", "white", "whiten", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "wicked", "wide", "widen", "widow", "widower", "width", "wife", "wild", "will", "win", "wind", "window", "wine", "wing", "winter", "wipe", "wire", "wisdom", "wise", "wish", "with", "within", "without", "witness", "woman", "wonder", "wood", "wooden", "wool", "woolen", "word", "work", "world", "worm", "worry", "worse", "worship", "worth", "would", "wound", "wrap", "wreck", "wrist", "write", "wrong", "yard", "year", "yellow", "yes", "yesterday", "yet", "yield", "you", "young", "youth", "zero"]
```

though it's good practice to save it somewhere else for easy editing.

an example using json:

```py
import json
# saving
with open('words.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(words, f)

# loading
words = []
with open('words.json', 'r') as f:
    words = json.load(f)
```

for a detailed explanation please see the [documemtation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)